# How to target one class when you are in loop?

Tags: php, jquery

All the PHP code is in the post loop so when adding a new post it gets also the buttons and when pressing one button it opens all buttons and containers

```
<div class="col-sm-1 ">
        <span class="btn btn-sm album-song">
            <a class="btn btn-sm show-album-song">&#8897;</a>
            <a class="btn btn-sm hide-album-song">&#8896;</a>
        </span>
    </div>

<div class="container album-songs-show-hide">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 name"><?php _e('Song Name', 'koband');?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php _e('Song Length', 'koband');?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php _e('Song Details', 'koband');?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #d6d6d6; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">         
    <?php foreach ($album_song_details[0] as  $value_song_details) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo $value_song_details['name-details']; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo $value_song_details['length']; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><?php echo $value_song_details['detail']; ?></div>

        <?php } ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery code goes here

```
$(".album-songs-show-hide").hide();
$(".hide-album-song").hide();
$(".show-album-song").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".album-songs-show-hide").slideDown(1000);// show container elements 
    $(".show-album-song").hide(); // button down hide
    $(".hide-album-song").show(); // button up show

});
```

Comment: That should have been written in the question

Comment: ok thanks i wrote it there

Comment: What's the question here? what problem you are facing??

Comment: When loop starts i loops all the posts.All Posts have one button. When button is pressed it should display content for the parent post, but when i press one button i presses all of them and shows the content of all the posts.

Comment: The problem with this question is that there's so many things seemingly going wrong... the HTML isn't valid, there's a `</div>` missing... the PHP loop doesnt wrap the row element, so it's just 1 row with a lot of content... there's only 1 button rendered that is supposed to somehow hide only 1 song, but there's not a single hint as to how that is even remotely attempted. I have no clue what you're trying to do here OP, your question and the code that you provide are contradicting eachother

Comment: There is much more code than i have provided here. All the <div> are closed and everything is working properly, but when i press one button it presses all the buttons because they are in the post loop, if I make one post it gets the the button with the same class and the container with the same class thats my problem. I want to target the button of specific post not all of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for commenting solutions but for me this was the working solution for you

```
$(".album-songs-show-hide").hide();
$(".hide-album-song").hide();
$(".show-album-song").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.container").find(".album-songs-show-hide").slideDown(1000);// hide container elemnts 
    $(".show-album-song").hide(); // button down hide
    $(".hide-album-song").show(); // button up show

});
```

Comment: Why you deleting your question? It would be nice if you check my answer instead deleting the question.